# MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException Selenium Python Firefox

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

so i'm pretty new to selenium and have a little test script i'm working on:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


url = "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0368226/reviews"


options = Options()
# options.add_argument('-headless')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

# Load the IMDb page
driver.get(url)

while True:
    try:
        button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'load-more-trigger')))
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.move_to_element(button).perform()
        button.click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
```

what i'd like for this script to do is to continuously click on the 'load more' button until it is no longer on the page. however, when i run this script, it presses the button once and then i receive this error: `selenium.common.exceptions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: (479, 4602) is out of bounds of viewport width (1280) and height (827)`

i've checked out numerous SO questions with solutions and none have done the trick so far. i feel like this is very close and i'm just overlooking something. any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use `ActionChains` to perform the click on the `Load More` button.

Here's the solution:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException

url = "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0368226/reviews"

options = Options()
# options.add_argument('-headless')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

# Load the IMDb page
driver.get(url)

while True:
    try:
        button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'load-more-trigger')))

        button.click()
    except (NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException):
        break
```

The while-loop will keep looking for the `Load More` button and keep clicking on it until there are no more `Load More` and finally it'll get timed out and break out of the loop.